# Notes being played by the right hand within a chord being played by the left

Tags: piano, sheet-music

I recently began playing a piece when I came across this:
[image: Every note in both the Treble and Bass are played uncomfortably close, and this occurs a lot in the song]

Any ideas on how to go about playing this?  Sneaking my right hand in between my left's fingers is quite comfortable and playing eight notes in the Treble with the Bass chord doesn't quite sound right.

Comment: I assume you meant quite uncomfortable to sneak your right hand between your left? I wouldn't worry about sustaining the `a` in this case - just play it it and get out of the way. If you're pedaling, it will be no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just play the A2 and G3 notes with the left and the C4 and E4 with the right hand here.  It's already where you need it and mostly idle.  You just have to make sure to match the articulation and volume of the left hand.

While you could also play everything but the bass note with the right hand regarding reach, that would require the right hand to split into separate personalities rhythmically.  Just taking over C4 and E4 means that they upper voice has settled already and you don't have to play a right hand chord *around* the fixed A3.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using your left hand will be that the first note of the bar won't be sustained. If your piano has a sostenuto (middle) pedal, one way you could avoid this is to catch the first note of the bar in the sostenuto pedal and then play the rest of the bass clef notes in the left hand.